# Generating a Histogram by Harmonic Number

Tags: signal-processing, octave

I am trying to create a program in GNU Octave to draw a histogram showing the fundamental and harmonics of a modified sinewave (the output from an SCR dimmer, which consists of a sinewave which is at zero until part way through the wave).

I've been able to generate the waveform and perform FFT to get a set of Frequency vs Amplitude points, however I am not sure how to convert this data into bins suitable for generating a histogram.

Sample code and an image of what I'm after below - thanks for the help!
[image: Harmonic number image]

```
clear();
vrms = 120;
freq = 60;
nCycles = 2;
level = 25;
vpeak = sqrt(2) * vrms;
sampleinterval = 0.00001;
num_harmonics = 10

disp("Start");

% Draw the waveform
x = 0 : sampleinterval : nCycles * 1 / freq; % time in sampleinterval increments
dimmed_wave = [];
undimmed_wave = [];
for i = 1 : columns(x)
  rad_value = x(i) * 2 * pi * freq;
  off_time =  mod(rad_value,  pi);
  on_time =  pi*(100-level)/100;
  if (off_time < on_time)
    dimmed_wave = [dimmed_wave, 0]; % in the dimmed period, value is zero
  else
    dimmed_wave = [dimmed_wave, sin(rad_value)]; % when not dimmed, value = sine
  endif
  undimmed_wave = [undimmed_wave, sin(rad_value)];
endfor

y = dimmed_wave * vpeak; % calculate instantaneous voltage
undimmed = undimmed_wave * vpeak;

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x*1000, y, '-', x*1000, undimmed, '--');
xlabel ("Time (ms)");
ylabel ("Voltage");

% Fourier Transform to determine harmonics
subplot(2,1,2)

N = length(dimmed_wave);  % number of points
fft_vals = abs(fftshift(fft(dimmed_wave))); % perform fft
frequency = [ -(ceil((N-1)/2):-1:1) ,0 ,(1:floor((N-1)/2)) ] *  1 / (N *sampleinterval);
plot(frequency, fft_vals);
axis([0,400]);
xlabel ("Frequency");
ylabel ("Amplitude");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know your base frequency (fundamental tone), let's call it `F`. `2*F` is the second harmonic, `3*F` the third, etc. You want to set histogram bin edges halfway between these: `1.5*F`, `2.5*F`, etc.

You have two periods in your input signal, therefore your (integer) base frequency is `k=2` (the value at `fft_vals[k+1]`, the first peak in your plot). The second harmonic is at `k=4`, the third one at `k=6`, etc.

So you would set your bins edges at `k = 1:2:end`.

In general, this would be `k = nCycles/2:nCycles:end`.

You can compute your bar graph according to our computed bin edges as follows:

```
fft_vals = abs(fft(dimmed_wave));
nHarmonics = 9;
edges = nCycles/2 + (0:nHarmonics)*nCycles;
H = cumsum(fft_vals);
H = diff(H(edges));
bar(1:nHarmonics,H);
```

Comment: Hm. I get that my bin edges should be 1.5*F (in this case 60Hz so my second harmonic bin is centered at 2*60=120Hz and the bin is from 120-150Hz, and so on) - but : my values at the output of the FFT are x,y coordinates where X is frequency and Y is amplitude.. how do I go about dividing those into bins and retaining the amplitude data? (sorry, my math is extremely rusty so I may not be explaining it well)..

Comment: @docsteer: you don't need to worry about the frequency computation in Hz. It's a lot easier using the "integer frequencies" `k`. See the edited question (I didn't run the code, I don't have Octave on this computer, please let me know if there are any typos).

Comment: Thanks - so I tried it and that does run, but doesn't give quite what I expected. Image [here](https://imgur.com/a/hS6jg1X) - Looking at the output of the FFT I have peaks at 60Hz (fundamental), 180Hz (3rd harmonic), 300Hz (5th harmonic) and so on. This is not reflected in the generated histogram.

Comment: @docsteer: You are right, `histc` made no sense, sorry. I have replaced that with different code that does produce the correct result.

Comment: With a bit of adjustment, that did it! I needed to discard the negative frequency component of the FFT output - once that was done, I got the right result. Final code is [here](https://gist.github.com/docsteer/bb5ec016b2a0f87099816b8df9bc9b55) and an image [here](https://imgur.com/i3e8ysa) in case this is useful for someone in the future. Thanks @Cris-Luengo for the help!

Comment: @docsteer: I forgot to mention to not use `fftshift`. If you leave that out, the `k` corresponds to the index -1 (edited the answer).